# Remove lines which contain 'logging'

Tags: command-line, bash

I have the following codes:

```
class Solution:
    def three_sum(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        nums.sort()
        output_set: set = set() #Notice 
        if len(nums) < 3:
            return []

        for i in range(len(nums)-2): #at least 2 element left
            sub_nums = nums[i+1:]
            sub_target = 0 - nums[i]
            logging.warning(f"sub_target: {sub_target}")

            two_sum_output = self.two_sum(sub_nums, sub_target)
            logging.warning(f"two_sum_output: {two_sum_output}")
            if two_sum_output != None:
                temp = { (nums[i],) + tuple(l) for l in two_sum_output }
                output_set.update(temp)
        output = [ list(t) for t in output_set] #conver to list
        logging.warning(f"final output count: {len(output)}:\n {output}")

        return output
```

I want to delete lines with `logging`,

`grep` could them

```
$ grep "logging" twoSum.py 
import logging
# logging.disable(level=CRITICAL)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.debug, 
logging.info(f"Start of twoSum Process {os.getpid()}")
# logging.debug(f"{ps.stdout.decode('utf-8')}")
            logging.info(f'find: {find} ')
            logging.info(f"j: {j}")
```

How could delete them?

Comment: Beware that the line containing `basicConfig` seems to continue on the next line and removing just the first line probably brakes your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `grep -v` and copy to another file

```
grep -v logging twoSum.py > logging-new
```

**Notes:**

- this does what you ask for, removing the physical lines containing 
  "logging". That might be a bad idea, as [noted by PerlDuck](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1127589/remove-lines-which-contain-logging?noredirect=1#comment1866586_1127589)
- if there is no space or strange char in the grepped text, you don't need " or '.